# Renaming the root node of XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, rename, root

I would like to rename my root node of an XML in Java.
I tried various solutions but none did work.

My code:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
 File xmlFile = new File("C:/test.xml");
 Document doc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));

 File xmiFile = new File("C:/test.xmi");
 FileMover.copyFile(xmlFile, xmiFile);      

 Document doc2 = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(xmiFile));
 doc2.importNode(doc.getDocumentElement(), true);

 doc2.getElementsByTagName("report");
 Node reportNode = doc2.getDocumentElement();
 Element reportElement = (Element) reportNode;
 doc2.renameNode(reportElement, "reports.dtd", "report:ReportType");

 Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
 Source source2 = new DOMSource(doc2.getDocumentElement());
 StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
 Result result2 = new StreamResult(out);
 transformer.transform(source2, result2);
```

Running the code, I get this exception:
Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.insertBefore(CoreDocumentImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.renameNode(CoreDocumentImpl.java:1047)
    at XMIConverter.main(XMIConverter.java:57)

Comment: Does your document have a namespace ?

Comment: You may have to lookup the namespace first , `reportElement.lookupPrefix("http://nameSpace")` then do the rename , doc2.renameNode(reportElement, "http://nameSpace", namespace + ":ReportType");'

Comment: I tried this and it leads to the same exception:
String namespace = reportElement.lookupPrefix("[http://www.omg.org/XMI](http://www.omg.org/XMI)");
  doc2.renameNode(reportElement, "reports.dtd", namespace + ":ReportType");

Comment: and I tried this (does not work as well):
String namespace = reportElement.lookupPrefix("[http://www.omg.org/XMI](http://www.omg.org/XMI)"; doc2.renameNode(reportElement, "reports.dtd", namespace + ":ReportType");